# URL only works with https and not http

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

All websites on my server only works with https:// and not http://. It doesn't redirect either..
Try:
frokungen.se and https://frokungen.se/
vetro.se and https://vetro.se/

Comment: There can be a problem within the unknown configuration of your unknown server. There can be a firewall with an unknown setup. And probably more unknown things. Your question essentially just tells us that your car is broken and ask us to figure out without any additional information what the problem is. Therefore I propose to close it as too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply and sorry for a very vague question. And since I basically dont know anything about servers it will be impossible to explain more, and nevertheless solve this. I just hoped there could be a known issue that would be solved. But thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your port 80 is open?